# Stop all timers when it is fired on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, timer

I am writing a function using ASP.Net C# to send some emails in every 10 seconds.
When I uploaded my codes, it had a problem and made an error so it fired the "catch" section, unfortunately, I did not have any code to stop my timer in this section and it is sending one email in every 10 seconds!
I fixed the error but the previous code is still running on server and it is sending the email without stopping!
I tried to disable the emails address which I used to send email by for couple of hours but it did not work.
Is there any code to stop that timer or all timer which are currently running on a server?

```
private void _delayTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //get all emails

        //check the current index and length of emails

        //if index < length
        //{
        //get the current email

        //send the email

        //increase index by 1

        //}
        //else
        //{
        //Stop the timer

        //}
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //these codes were not here and the timer did not stop!    
        System.Timers.Timer timer = (System.Timers.Timer)sender; // Get the timer that fired the event
        timer.Stop(); // Stop the timer that fired the event
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the timer started? Did you upload a new web.config to unload the current running appdomain?

Comment: how to do that? (uploading a new web.config to unload the current running appdomain?)

Comment: I assume your website has a web.config? If you put an update web.config on your website asp.net makes sure your website is restarted. if you only deploy a new dll that is not guaranteed to happen.